# Multiple API Calls in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, fetch-api

I am making an app where I receive data from an API. Once I get this data I want to make another call to the same API with the endpoint that I got from the first call.

```
fetch(req)
    .then((response)=>(
        response.json()
    )).then((json)=>{
        console.log(json)
        json.meals.map((obj)=>{
            let url = `https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.mashape.com/recipes/${obj.id}/information`
            let req = new Request(url,{
            method: 'GET',
            headers: header
        })
        fetch(req)
        .then((response)=>(
        response.json()
        )).then((json)=>{
            console.log(json);
        this.setState((prevState)=>{
                recipe: prevState.recipe.push(json)
        })
        })
        })
        this.setState(()=>{
            return{
                data: json
            }
        })
    })
```

I am making two fetch requests here but the problem is the data from the first response is output after second fetch request. Also the `state: data` gets set before `state: recipe` and the components render with the data from `state: data`.

```
render(){
      return(
        <div className="my-container">
        <EnterCalorie getData={this.getData}/>
        <MealData data={this.state.data} recipe={this.state.recipe}/>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

How can i make sure both get passed down at the same time?

Comment: resolve your promise and call again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 3 return `return response.json()` instead of nothing (`undefined`).

Update:

```
const toJson = response => response.json()

fetch(req)
    .then(toJson)
    .then(json => {
        this.setState(() => {
            return {
                data: json
            }
        })

        return json
    })
    .then((json) => {
        console.log(json)
        const promises = json.meals.map((obj) => {
            let url = `https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.mashape.com/recipes/${obj.id}/information`
            let req = new Request(url, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: header
            })
            return fetch(req)
                .then(toJson)
                .then((json) => {
                    console.log(json);
                    this.setState((prevState) => ({
                        recipe: prevState.recipe.push(json)
                    }))
                })
        })

        return Promise.all(promises)
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('job done')
    })
```

You need to map your array into promises. Then use `Promise.all` to wait for them the get resolved.

There was parenthesis missing from:

```
this.setState((prevState)=>{
    recipe: prevState.recipe.push(json)
})
```

A sidenote, this whole stuff should be refactored. You're not going to get far with this code style / code complexity.

Comment: that is the syntax of returning if only one statment is there

Comment: i get this error : `prevState.recipe.push is not a function` and this `Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.`

Comment: It means you are calling fetch from the wrong place. Call it from the `componentDidMount` hook.

Comment: *it is very likely

Comment: I made a parent component to resolve the issue. The code was definitely way to complex and I was getting confused myself. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch(req) // req no1
    .then((response)=>(
        response.json()
    )).then((json)=>{
        console.log(json)
        json.meals.map((obj)=>{
            let url = `https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.mashape.com/recipes/${obj.id}/information`
            let req = new Request(url,{
            method: 'GET',
            headers: header
        })
        fetch(req) // req no 1 called again
        .then((response)=>(
        response.json()
        )).then((json1)=>{
            console.log(json1);
            this.setState((prevState)=>{
                recipe: prevState.recipe.push(json1)
            })
            this.setState(()=>{
                return{
                    data: json
            })
        })
        })
        })

    })
```

I think you are calling api with same req parameters again in the second fetch call

Comment: I am getting my data back for both calls but `state: data` gets passed down and gets rendered out and after that `state: recipe` is fetched.

Comment: yes that is because you have done that setstate in the first call itself and being asunchronous in nature your data is updated first

Answer (score 0):

This is a callback hell, please look for **Promise races**, and check the **all()** promise method.